# Github Pages tarda demasiado en subir cambios

Tags: github, deployment, github-pages

tengo un repositorio con Github Pages, ayer hice cambios en el código y los subi a Github, pero ya van 11 horas y los cambios aun no se reflejan en Pages, "**Deployed by GitHub Pages on behalf of @GabrielNicolosi2022 GabrielNicolosi2022 11 hours ago (Waiting)**", es normal tanto tiempo?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Eventualmente podría ser, recuerdo que hay una página dónde verificar el estado de los servicios de github, en alguna oportunidad tuve este tipo de demora (no tanto tiempo) y se debía a algún problema, servicio caído o en mantenimiento